# supertuxkart 1.0-3 are tracks lock or unlock?

Tags: games

I've played [supertuxkart 1.0-3](https://supertuxkart.net/Main_Page) on Ubuntu 19.10 and play **single player** for some time.

now to go head I have to unlock a track(map)

to do this I have to win all previous track

How can see if a track is been win by me?

at the screen all have the same aspect.

### Update

I forget to tell I have read all the FAQ and issue I have found.
This is my **players.xml**:

```xml
<players version="1" >
    <current player="leonardo"/>
    <player name="leonardo" guest="false" use-frequency="21"
            icon-filename="1.png"
            unique-id="1" saved-session="true"
            saved-user="123310" saved-token="8496cf4ce7b708e8c336ab4a"
            last-online-name="lesar" last-was-online="false"
            remember-password="true"
            default-kart-color="0">
      <story-mode first-time="true">
        <abyss solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <candela_city solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <cocoa_temple solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <cornfield_crossing solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <fortmagma solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <gp1 solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <gp2 solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <gp3 solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <gp4 solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <granparadiso_island solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <green_valley solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <hacienda solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <lighthouse solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <mansion solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <mines solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <minigolf solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <olivermath solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <sandtrack solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <scotland solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <snowmountain solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <snowpeak solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <stk_enterprise solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <unlock_bonus_kart1 solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <unlock_bonus_kart2 solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <unlock_supertux solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <volcano_island solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <xr591 solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
        <zengarden solved="none" best_while_slower="false"/>
      </story-mode>
      <achievements online="true"> 
    ...
```

All values are false but I have played and won all tracks unless I find the one blocked.

The file is read and write for my user.

Comment: Win races in the story mode to unlock features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

In irc chat tell me that I have to play in story mode and win in that mode to unlock **single player** mode.

I have not find this information on faq.

In the game help is write that, one must win the track, but I suppose I have to win track in *single player* to unlock in *single player*.

win in story mode to unlock in single player is alien idea to me.

I will try and then update here.

### Updated

It is true

regards

Answer (score 1):

The last question in the [FAQ](https://supertuxkart.net/FAQ) tells you to find the track completion data, open the folder "config-0.10" then open the file "players.xml"; if a track shows as *none* you have not played it in **Story** mode; ignore the *false* value.

That folder will be found in either

- $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/supertuxkart/config-0.10 (first choice),
- ~/.config/supertuxkart/config-0.10 (second choice), or in
- ~/.supertuxkart/config-0.10 (third choice).

If you don't see a folder named "config-0.10" look for a folder which starts with "config-" but ends with a different number, as the FAQ looks like it was written for version 0.10 but you are running a newer version.

Sometimes FAQs are not updated as the app grows and changes, a problem common to all open source and freeware. I suspect this is the case, as the FAQ refers to version 0.10 whereas the current release is version 1.1 .

Comment: I update the question: I have missed some information believing it was a common problem.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: players.xml I have posted is in /home/leonardo/.config/supertuxkart/config-0.10/players.xml and all story are 'solved="none" best_while_slower="false"' but the first 8 track I have played and win

Comment: I have played not in story mode but as single player!!!